# Delete null values (cells) from 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, null

I have following array:

```
Point[][] points;
```

It is initialized using other array that contains null values.
What I want is to delete null cells, so the new array will not contain any null values.

For example:

```
Other Array: P, P, P
             P, P, P
             N, P, N
             N, P, N

New Array:   P, P, P
             P, P, P
                P,
                P,
```

How can I achieve it?

Update:

Is it good way to do it?

```
Point[][] temp = cv.getPtStroke();
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (; i < temp.length && temp[i]!= null; i++) {}
Point[][] temp1 = new Point[i][];

i = 0;
for (; i < temp.length && temp[i]!= null; i++)
{
    for (; j < temp[i].length && temp[i][j]!= null; j++){}
    temp1[i] = new Point[j];
}
```

Update:
Problem Solved:

```
Point[][] temp = cv.getPtStroke();
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < temp.length && temp[i]!= null; i++) {}
            Point[][] temp1 = new Point[i][];
            i = 0;
            for (; i < temp.length && temp[i]!= null; i++)
            {
                int j = 0;
                for (; j < temp[i].length && temp[i][j]!= null; j++){}
                temp1[i] = new Point[j];
            }

            int k = 0;
            int temp1XSize = temp1.length;
            int temp1YSize = 0;
            for (; k < temp1XSize; k++)
            {
                temp1YSize = temp1[k].length;
                int l = 0;
                for (; l < temp1YSize; l++){
                    temp1[k][l] = temp[k][l];
                }
            }
```

Do you know any better method?

Comment: You should add what language are you using (Java, Javascript, etc.). For each language, could be many different ways to do it.

Comment: I use Java (Android SDK)

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Array in major case - this impossible. Array have "fix" size. But in some programming language it is possible by using ArrayList, List, HasTable and etc entities.

For example in PHP Arrays wor like ArrayList (or List). In JavaScript you may use object instead of array.

Example for PHP:

```
//Origin Array
$array = array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array(null,2, null),
    array(null,2,null),
);
// New array
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $i => $row) {
    $result[$i] = array();
    foreach ($array[$i] as $j => $cell) {
        if ($cell !== null) {
            $result[$i][$j] = $cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for JavaScript:

```
var array = [
    [1,2,3],
    [null,2,null],
    [null,2,null]
];
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    result[i] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++ ) {
        if (array[i][j] !== null) {
             result[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible in plain Java? I am trying to design application for Android. Is there any walk around? I cant change old array and I need new array to be an array.

Comment: Posible with using anther entites (not array) somthing like List or HashTable

Comment: What do you think about my updated solution? I think I achieved what I wanted.